# Scroll all data in slick JS

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I want to scroll all the data by slick JS. [See this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16U8Y.png)
Initially it will be scrolling vertically automatically, when user want to scroll he/she will must be able to scroll all data in slider.

As in image there are 50 blocks are scrolling vertically, I want to view all blocks while scrolling down.

How can I manage this scenario with Slick

Comment: Please give an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Please check above image, As in image there are 50 blocks are scrolling vertically, I want to view all blocks while scrolling down.

How can I manage this scenario with Slick Image:http://i.stack.imgur.com/16U8Y.png

Comment: Any Update please!